# 'with' method on Eloquent returns empty collection in HasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lamp

I'm having this issue:
I have defined two models with a HasMany relationship like this:

DepartamentoPersonalizado.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use App\Models\LocalidadPersonalizada;

class DepartamentoPersonalizado extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'departamentos_personalizados';
    //I've tried:
    //protected $with = ['localidades'];

    public function localidades ():HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(LocalidadPersonalizada::class,'departamento_id');
    }

}
```

LocalidadPersonalizada.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\DepartamentoPersonalizado;

class LocalidadPersonalizada extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'localidades_personalizadas';
    
    
    public function departamento () {
          return $this->belongsTo(DepartamentoPersonalizado::class,'id');
    }
    
}
```

When I do in Tinker:

```
> use App\Models\DepartamentoPersonalizado;
> $departamentos= DepartamentoPersonalizado::all()->first()->localidades;
```

I get:

```
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6778
    all: [
      App\Models\LocalidadPersonalizada {#6780
        nombre_localidad: "General San Martin",
        departamento_id: "06371",
        id: 1,
      },
      App\Models\LocalidadPersonalizada {#6781
        nombre_localidad: "Villa Lynch",
        departamento_id: "06371",
        id: 2,
      },
      App\Models\LocalidadPersonalizada {#6782
        nombre_localidad: "Villa Maipu",
        departamento_id: "06371",
        id: 3,
      },
      App\Models\LocalidadPersonalizada {#6783
        nombre_localidad: "Villa Ballester",
        departamento_id: "06371",
        id: 4,
      },
...
```

But when I do:

```
> $departamentos = DepartamentoPersonalizado::with('localidades')->get();
```

I get:

```
= Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6770
    all: [
      App\Models\DepartamentoPersonalizado {#6771
        departamento_datos_gob: "Ciudad Libertador San Martin",
        departamento_osm: "General San Martin",
        id_provincia: "06",
        id: "06371",
        reemplazar_agregar: 0,
        localidades: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6765
          all: [],
        },
      },
      App\Models\DepartamentoPersonalizado {#6767
        departamento_datos_gob: "La Matanza",
        departamento_osm: "La Matanza",
        id_provincia: "06",
        id: "06427",
        reemplazar_agregar: 1,
        localidades: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#6790
          all: [],
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

I mean, I got an empty collection at attribute 'localidades', and I need to have a nested collection in it.

I'd like to use the 'protected $with = ['localidades']' in DepartamentoPersonalizado to get the result I want by default.

Any idea of what's going on? Any additional information needed?

Thanks a lot!

Leandro

Comment: The second parameter in belongsTo must be the foreign key name in your current table, so it should be `departamento_id` (or anything else that acts as a foreign key in this model)
For more information, look at [this](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one) it's similar to belongsTo and hasMany

Comment: If you have everything configured properly, you should be able to do `DepartamentoPersonalizado::first()->localidades->toJson() === DepartamentoPersonalizado::with('localidades')->first()->localidades->toJson()`, and that should be `true` (tested with `php artisan tinker`, then some local models and relationships). What does that return for you?

Comment: @TimLewis
```
> use App\Models\DepartamentoPersonalizado;
> DepartamentoPersonalizado::first()->localidades->toJson() === DepartamentoPersonalizado::with('localidades')->first()->localidades->toJson()
= false
```

Comment: Very interesting! So something does indeed seem to be defined wrong (or my way of testing that is flawed, but I did test a few different Models). Is one of those `empty`? You can test with `->count()` instead of `->toJson()`, but that can easily result in false-positives.

Comment: [link] https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGVUG.png

Comment: I do notice that `departamento_id` has a leading `0`. What is the datatype in the database? I wonder if Laravel is confusing this value as a `int` when it should be a `string` (or vice-versa), and `06371` might be treated as `6371` instead (I've had similar issues happen when we migrated a `varchar` column to an `int` column). I'm not sure why it would only be happening when using `->with()` though, since `-> localidades` _should_ return the same with or without the use of `->with('localidades')` 

Comment: @TimLewis In fact, there was the problem

Comment: Excellent! Sidenote, I would still recommend have an auto-incrementing `id` column of some kind. If you have to manually define an `id`, it should probably not be the `primary key` column. Common cases or `id` and something like an `order_number`; `order_number` can be used as a unique, primary display key, but `id` would be used for indexing, PK/FK relationships, etc. This can definitely still function without one, but my 2¢ worth. Glad you got this fixed regardless 

Answer (score 0):

Since my 'id' in 'departamentos_personalizados' was a String instead of Integer, I needed to do:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use App\Models\LocalidadPersonalizada;

class DepartamentoPersonalizado extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table = 'departamentos_personalizados';
    public $incrementing=false;
    protected $with = ['localidades'];
    protected $casts=['reemplazar_agregar' => 'boolean'];

    public function localidades ():HasMany {
        
        return $this->hasMany(LocalidadPersonalizada::class,'departamento_id','id');
    }

}
```

Now it's working as expected.